# combining columns for a new date format in python

Tags: python, datetime, time, formatting, multiple-columns

I'm new to Python so any help or advice is very appreciated and sorry if I'm asking very obvious things. 
I'm having the following data :

```
  WMO_NO  YEAR  MONTH  DAY  HOUR  MINUTE   H     PS    T  RH    TD WDIR   WSP
0    4018  2006      1    1    11      28  38  988.6  0.9  98   0.6  120  14.4
1    4018  2006      1    1    11      28  46  987.6  0.5  91  -0.7  122  15.0
2    4018  2006      1    1    11      28  57  986.3  0.5  89  -1.1  124  15.5
3    4018  2006      1    1    11      28  66  985.1  0.5  90  -1.1  126  16.0
4    4018  2006      1    1    11      28  74  984.1  0.4  90  -1.1  127  16.5
```

I would like to combine the YEAR  MONTH  DAY  HOUR  MINUTE  into a new column formatted as YEAR:MONTH:DAY:HOUR:MINUTE ( and then index the T data with this column) and do some analysis. 
My first question is how to I create such a new column ? The second is can I do comparisons and analysis on this column like ( YEAR:MONTH:DAY:HOUR:MINUTE > 2007:04:13:04:44)?
Cheers.

Comment: Some problem with my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then if necessary [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with custom format, check http://strftime.org/:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['YEAR','MONTH','DAY','HOUR','MINUTE']])
df['date_new'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M')
print (df)
   WMO_NO  YEAR  MONTH  DAY  HOUR  MINUTE   H     PS    T  RH   TD  WDIR  \
0    4018  2006      1    1    11      28  38  988.6  0.9  98  0.6   120   
1    4018  2006      1    1    11      28  46  987.6  0.5  91 -0.7   122   
2    4018  2006      1    1    11      28  57  986.3  0.5  89 -1.1   124   
3    4018  2006      1    1    11      28  66  985.1  0.5  90 -1.1   126   
4    4018  2006      1    1    11      28  74  984.1  0.4  90 -1.1   127   

    WSP                date          date_new  
0  14.4 2006-01-01 11:28:00  2006:01:01:11:28  
1  15.0 2006-01-01 11:28:00  2006:01:01:11:28  
2  15.5 2006-01-01 11:28:00  2006:01:01:11:28  
3  16.0 2006-01-01 11:28:00  2006:01:01:11:28  
4  16.5 2006-01-01 11:28:00  2006:01:01:11:28
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data consists of integers instead of strings you can use this to create a datetime index:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

columns = ['ID', 'Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute']
data = [ ['1', 2006, 1, 1, 11, 28],
         ['2', 2006, 1, 1, 11, 29]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

df.index = df.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime(x['Year'], x['Month'], x['Day'], x['Hour'], x['Minute']), axis=1)
```